# COUNTIF based on multiple criteria concatenated in single cell

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, countif

First time poster, long time reader!

I'm looking for some help with a COUNTIF style formula. I have a table which contains circa 100 rows per day and what I need to do is to count the occurences of certain criteria in the table on a summary sheet. The issue is that the COUNTIF must count the items based on multiple possible values which are concatenated into one cell. See below as an example of what I am looking for:

`Criteria

1.) A,B,C,D

2.) 1,2,3,4`

`Items
A
B
D
1
2
7`

What I need is for the result of criteria 1 to be 3, and the result of criteria 2 to be 2.

What would be my best option in this scenario? I have attempted to create a function in vba to delimit the cells and maybe try to incorporate that into a COUNTIF/SUMPRODUCT. See the code I am using below:

> *Function EXPLODE(str As String, Optional delimiter As Variant) As Variant
>         EXPLODE = Split(str, delimiter)
>     End Function*

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, if you're interested in a purely formula-based solution, with your *Items* in A1:A6, *Age* in D1:D6 and your first comma-separated string (e.g. A,B,C,D) in B1:

In C1:

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(B1))),LEN(B1)*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&1+LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))))-1)+1,LEN(B1))),$D$1:$D$6,">3"))

Copy down as required to give similar results for strings in B2, B3, etc.

Regards

Comment: Ah, apologies. Re-reading your post I realise that you may actually be after exact matches within your range, not partial. If there is an entry in the Item column of e.g. "1BZ0", my current formula will consider that to be a "match" for "B". Let me know if that is in fact the case and I will amend the formula. Of course, if, as in the example you give, the entries are all single characters, then this is not an issue...

Comment: This has worked a treat! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: * My criteria will be considerably bigger than single letters so this should not be an issue. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm a bit confused. So you don't actually want to perform EXACT matches? If you DO want exact matches, then this formula may well give incorrect results, as per the example I gave in my last comment.

Comment: The criteria in my example were very simple compared to what I will actually be entering. My criteria will be account names which could be 20 characters long. If it is looking for partial matches I don't believe it will be able to find anything only exact matches. Am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: I wouldn't know without seeing your data, but if you had e.g. a criteria string "A123,B456,C789" and you searched in a range containing (in individual cells) "A123" and "B456C789", you would get an answer of 3, not 2 as you might hope for. Do you see what I mean? I can happily change the formula to apply to exact matches only if you want.

Comment: What's more, if partial matching is not actually a REQUIREMENT, then the formula can be made considerably more efficient, not least since it would no longer need to be array-entered.

Comment: That would be great if you could. Partial matching would not be a requirement of the formula. Also I will eventually need to append extra criteria based on another column, would this change the formula in any way?

Comment: I've amended in the post. Note that this is no longer an array formula (at least in the sense that it doesn't require entering with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER). Can you test? Not sure what you mean by "append criteria based on another column", though. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I've tested it and it seems to be counting how many of the criteria are in the table rather than how many times each of the criteria appear in total. Also apologies for my poor explanation, I want to be able to add another criteria at some point. Currently I only need to count the items in the table which match the "1,2,3,4" criteria but if at some point I may need to count the items that not only matched "1,2,3,4" but also where the item value is >3 for example. Sorry if I am not explaining this well.

Comment: Apologies. I misunderstood what you wanted. I have a couple of amended solutions, though each in turn is dependent on what your actual datatypes are. You say: "My criteria will be account names which could be 20 characters long", so I assume this format also applies to the Item names? If so, can you confirm that NONE of these Item Names is a pure numeric? I'm a little confused here, since your latest criterion involves a numerical comparison (">3"), though if these Item entries are of the form you describe above (i.e. 20 character-long strings), then I don't fully understand this comparison.

Comment: Sorry bad example, my datatype will be generally text or alphanumeric. My added criteria would be based on another column. So say for example each row has two fields, the "Items" column as per above and another column called "Age" which will have a numeric datatype. If I was to count based on my "A,B,C,D" criteria for "Items" could I also include a criteria to say that only count items where "Age" value is greater than 3? Apologies for taking up so much of your time over this.

Comment: Not at all. I've amended as per your requests, with the assumption that the "Age" data is in D1:D6, and everything else as previously stated. Again, this is NOT an array formula. Let me know if that's what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIFS` in combination with your `Split` function **Explode**.

So, your function can return an Array which can be fitted into multiple cells using `Ctrl-Shift-Return` and then the function

```
=COUNTIFS(*ItemRange*, *Criteria1_fromSplit*, *ItemRange*, *Criteria2_fromSplit*....)
```

That way you can split the cell into say 5-10 values depending on how many concatenations you expect at maximum and build the `COUNTIFS` function.

Comment: Thanks very much for your swift response! One or two questions, would this require splitting the concatenated cell out into multiple separate cells first before using them as criteria? And also how do I reference the array created by the EXPLODE function?

Comment: In your `EXPLODE` function, create a Variant array of dimensions `(row, col)` where row = number of split results, and col = 1. i.e. run a loop and fill up this `OutputArray(i,1) = SplitResultVariable(i)`, and then in the last line of the function put `EXPLODE = OutputArray`. That way when you highlight rows, say B1:B10 and type `= EXPLODE(...)` and do a `Ctrl-Shift-Return`, you get an array output.

Comment: you cannot refer to the full array created by EXPLODE, you'll have to estimate that you want at max 10 criteria, and then split it over 10 cells and use each of those values as individual criteria. So your string could split into 4 substrings and so be it, only first 4 of those are used, etc.

Comment: Ok perfect, I'll give that a try. At the moment I only have 11 possible criteria, but I can't guarantee that this won't increase in the future. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool, you can add extra number of criteria, just in case : ) And if it was helpful, you may mark this as answered. Tks.